# Add element outside of an iframe

Tags: iframe

I have 2 vue projects. In one I am creating a simple component:

```js
<template>
    <button @click="importIframe">Click me</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    importIframe() {
      console.log(parent.document)
    },
   }
</script>
```

In the other project of vue, import with an iframe the project 01 with a script:

```js
<script src="http://localhost:8081/myiframe.js"></script>
```

Project 01 is running in localhost:8081 and 02 in 8080. I have a my iframe script which is the one that creates the iframe and imports it into the body.

This is myiframe.js script:

```js
ready(function () {
  initIframe()
})

/**
 * Auto execute javascript function
 * @param callbackFunction
 */
function ready(callbackFunction) {
  if (document.readyState != 'loading') callbackFunction()
  else document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callbackFunction)
}

/**
 * Initialize iframe
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
function initIframe() {
    // Set url
    const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8081'

    // Create div tag
    const divContainer = document.createElement('div')
    divContainer.setAttribute('id', 'container-iframe')

    // Create iframe tag
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
    iframe.setAttribute('src', baseUrl)

    divContainer.appendChild(iframe)
    document.body.appendChild(divContainer)
}
```

What I want to achieve is that by clicking on the button. I should create a new div inside # container-iframe. If I select the iframe container it returns null. And if I select the parent of the iframe with parent.document. It gives me a security error, how can I add an element to the parent of the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue when you work with cross-domains.
Good news is that we have `postMessage` to send events between the iframe and the parent.

In the child (iframe button):

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    importIframe() {
      parent.postMessage("clicked", "*");
    },
   }
</script>
```

Then listen in paranet:

```
function listenToChild() {
   var eventMethod = window.addEventListener
                ? "addEventListener"
                : "attachEvent";
        var eventer = window[eventMethod];
        var messageEvent = eventMethod === "attachEvent"
            ? "onmessage"
            : "message";

    eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
        
        // if (e.origin !== 'http://the-trusted-iframe-origin.com') return;
        
        if (e.data === "clicked" || e.message === "clicked") 
            alert('Message from iframe just came!');

        // create a new div inside # container-iframe.
        
        console.log(e);
    }); 
}
```

Then add it to page load (ready function in your case)

More about the postMessage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

https://gist.github.com/cirocosta/9f730967347faf9efb0b